# How to tie back iTunes connect Subscription Status URL to a unique user

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

Hello I am currently trying to take advantage of the Subscription Status URL that iTunes connect gives you to get updates on a auto renewable in app subscription.

I have my endpoint up and running, and I am getting all the receipt info I need and the status of the update, however I have no current way of tying this update back to a specific user of my application.

For example, every user of my app has a UUID, and in a perfect world I would somehow like to tell Apple during a purchase which user uuid purchased this subscription and then get that UUID back in the POST request from the Subscription Status URL.

Is this possible?

Comment: what you want to do is not possible directly with StoreKit APIs somehow as all the subscriptions are managed with an associated AppleID.

Comment: Is there a currently a way to get the associated appleID?

Comment: No way to fetch associated AppleID. but you can send receipt data on your server & link with it UUID of your app.Download latest receipt on basis of UUID & verify with Storekit whenever required.

Comment: Are you talking about the `/verifyReceipt` url or the new status update notifications that apple sends?

Comment: @JacobEiting talking about the new status update notification.

Answer (score 0):

You have identified what I consider to be one of the biggest flaws in StoreKit, that the receipt does not contain a way to identify the user (iTunes account in this case).

The way around this is: When your users make a purchase and your app processes a transaction, you need to post the transaction identifier (and probably the receipt data) to your backend and associate it with your user's backend record. Then when you get a push from Apple, you can look up the user it relates to by transaction id.

This is not an ideal solution, since different app users can be sharing a receipt via the same iTunes account and other edge cases like that, buts it is a good as you can do with the way app receipts work.